# How can I get FreeDOS to see >8Gb using CF-IDE

Tags: hard-drive, bios, freedos, compact-flash

I am trying to install FreeDOS onto a 16Gb SANDISK CF card booting from a USB stick.

The system BIOS is set to autodetect and shows the CF card as a 16Gb HDD. However when I boot the FreeDOS installer even with FAT32 enabled FDISK shows only a 8025Mb drive. I have tried both "Large" and "LBA" addressing modes.

If I add a primary partition (I have tried the full 8025Mb and 250Mb partition sizes) the installer appears to quickformat correctly but then gives this error:

```
DOS Area: unknown command given to driver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8025Mb is the DOS FDISK LBA limit. [Notes on DOS FDISK Command](https://www.rigacci.org/docs/biblio/online/firmware/fdisk.htm)

> Some Considerations for Large Drives
>
> DOS 6.22 FDISK
>
> Does not support drives over 8.4GB. Will show total drive size for
>   drives over 8.4GB as 7553MB or 8025MB or some similar value which will
>   vary depending on how the drive is being handled by the BIOS.

I used [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) to create a partition utilising the whole disk and then the FreeDOS installation went ahead smoothly.